# MarkLogic SwitchCase code for XML transformation removing root node namespace declarations

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have XML structure like the one below(Sample XML). I want to change the img tags value and change them to relative path.Each XML document can contain more than 100s of img tags. My code works for most of the part, except the fact that  the namespace declations that I have in the root node is added to the individual nodes who is referencing the namespace, and I don't want that to happen.

**Sample XML:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test:document transformVersion="0.0.25" xmlns:test="test.data" xmlns:csp="test.csp" xmlns:cfg="test.cfg">
    <data>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="DataboxTitle">Test Image</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/document/1234.jpg" data-stl="height:107px;width:223px;" srcset="https://www.google.com/images/document/1234.jpg 320w" data-image-title="Test Image"/>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="DataboxTitle">Test Image</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/document/1234.jpg" data-stl="height:107px;width:223px;" srcset="https://www.google.com/images/document/1234.jpg 320w" data-image-title="Test Image"/>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="DataboxTitle">Test Image</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/document/1234.jpg" data-stl="height:107px;width:223px;" srcset="https://www.google.com/images/document/1234.jpg 320w" data-image-title="Test Image"/>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>
            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/document/1234.jpg" data-stl="height:107px;width:223px;" srcset="https://www.google.com/images/document/1234.jpg 320w" data-image-title="Test Image"/>
        </p>
    </data>
    <test:volumes>
        <test:test>test</test:test>
    </test:volumes>
    <csp:volumes>tested</csp:volumes>
</test:document>
```

In my SwitchCase Code below, I know the namespaces are getting added individually due to the code '/*' in the $doc variable declaration, but without that I will need a for each loop which screws up the other logic. I just want the img tags attribute values to change without changing anything else in the output xml, please suggest a way out.

**XQUERY CODE:**

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare variable $doc := fn:doc("/c/temp/test.xml")/*;
declare variable $docId := '1928862612025434112';

declare function local:createTag($docId,$imagePath)
{
let $srcOld := fn:data($imagePath/@src)
let $imageName := fn:tokenize($srcOld,"/")[fn:last()]
return fn:concat("/",$docId,"/media/",$imageName)
};

declare function local:createSrcSetTag($docId,$imagePath)
{
let $srcSetsOld := fn:data($imagePath/@srcset)
for $srcSet in fn:tokenize($srcSetsOld, ",")
let $imageLength := fn:tokenize($srcSet," ")[fn:last()]
let $imageName := fn:tokenize($srcSet,"/")[fn:last()]
let $imageNewPath := fn:concat("/",$docId,"/media/",$imageName)
return fn:concat($imageNewPath,"," )
};

declare function local:change($node as node()*) as node()*
{
  typeswitch($node)
  case element(img) return
    element { xs:QName(fn:local-name($node)) } 
    {
    let $image := $node
    let $path := xdmp:path($image)
    let $data-stl := fn:data($image/@data-stl)
    let $data-image-title := fn:data($image/@data-image-title)
    let $srcOld := fn:data($image/@src)
    let $srcSetsOld := fn:data($image/@srcset)
    let $srcNew := local:createTag($docId,$image) 
    let $srcSetsNew := local:createSrcSetTag($docId,$image) 
    return (attribute {'src'}{$srcNew}, attribute {'data-stl'}{$data-stl},attribute {'srcset'}{$srcSetsNew}, attribute {'data-image-title'}{$data-image-title} )
    }  
  case element() return 
    element {fn:node-name($node) } {
      $node/@*,
      $node/node() ! local:change(.)
    }   
  default return $node
};
 local:change(($doc))
```

This is my output after transformation:

```
<test:document transformVersion="0.0.25" xmlns:test="test.data">
<data>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="DataboxTitle">Test Image</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>
                    <img src="/1928862612025434112/media/1234.jpg" data-stl="height:107px;width:223px;" srcset="/1928862612025434112/media/1234.jpg 320w," data-image-title="Test Image"/>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="DataboxTitle">Test Image</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>
                    <img src="/1928862612025434112/media/1234.jpg" data-stl="height:107px;width:223px;" srcset="/1928862612025434112/media/1234.jpg 320w," data-image-title="Test Image"/>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="DataboxTitle">Test Image</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>
                    <img src="/1928862612025434112/media/1234.jpg" data-stl="height:107px;width:223px;" srcset="/1928862612025434112/media/1234.jpg 320w," data-image-title="Test Image"/>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <img src="/1928862612025434112/media/1234.jpg" data-stl="height:107px;width:223px;" srcset="/1928862612025434112/media/1234.jpg 320w," data-image-title="Test Image"/>
    </p>
</data>
<test:volumes>
    <test:test>test</test:test>
</test:volumes>
<csp:volumes xmlns:csp="test.csp">tested</csp:volumes>
```

Comment: Why is this a problem? Albeit in a different namespace format, your output appears to be functionally equivalent.

Comment: This isn't a problem per say, as the content remains the same, but we want to compare apples to apples, is there a way to doing that and not transform the xml in any way? We aren't sure if this approach breaks anything else  in the prod in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so hard to keep the namespace declarations on the elements they occurred, just make sure to copy them over along with attributes and elements. You can use `$node/namespace::*` for this purpose:

```
declare function local:change($node as node()*) as node()*
{
  typeswitch($node)
  case element(img) return
    element { xs:QName(fn:local-name($node)) } 
    {
    let $image := $node
    let $path := xdmp:path($image)
    let $data-stl := fn:data($image/@data-stl)
    let $data-image-title := fn:data($image/@data-image-title)
    let $srcOld := fn:data($image/@src)
    let $srcSetsOld := fn:data($image/@srcset)
    let $srcNew := local:createTag($docId,$image) 
    let $srcSetsNew := local:createSrcSetTag($docId,$image) 
    return (attribute {'src'}{$srcNew}, attribute {'data-stl'}{$data-stl},attribute {'srcset'}{$srcSetsNew}, attribute {'data-image-title'}{$data-image-title} )
    }  
  case element() return 
    element {fn:node-name($node) } {
      $node/namespace::*,
      $node/@*,
      $node/node() ! local:change(.)
    }   
  default return $node
};
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Your posted implementation is also a good example for testing your other code - in general* XML processing code should not depend on the specific declaration style for namespaces, rather only on the namespace attribute in the internal XDM model.  If code breaks due to changes in formatting only that would be a great unit test to inject in order to find and fix such code.

** Of course there are reasons for code to explicitly depend on format or namespace declaration differences, such the code that would implement the above unit test -- it would need to explicitly control the result formats as well as detect semantically identical format differences, interacting with external services, or particularly tedious, extracting sub-nodes out of the XML and preserving the desired (and only the desired) namespaces, text serialization optimizations etc, or --

> `<expletive deleted>`

-- generating  XHTML.